# Why doesn't wordpress need to include anything before using a function

Tags: php, wordpress

When I use `get_header();` in index.php, it automatically load the header.php file and and need not to include anything in the page.

Generally index.php is the main page. everything should be include there before it was called. Am I wrong?

Comment: It always call `index.php` first, your are certainly looking at just template code. but actully execution start from main `index.php` at root which eventually call templates 'index.php`

Comment: did U have tried to create new file php and try call the function get_header(). it show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are checking index.php inside the theme. But that is not the entry point to the site, but the index.php file in the wordpress root. There you can see it has included some files and inside those they have included some other files. Like wise file including functions are written in the wordpress core codes. So, you don't want to worry about including files in your theme. if you call get_header() function, the function itself has coded so that the relevant file to be included. If you are going to use a separate file to code functionality other than standard wordpress theme files, you'll have to include it at the top of functions.php